# socket io admin ui not display all information

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am first time experiencing socketio Admin UI. I am facing an issue, I m not abale to view all feature in dashboard. when i visit on `https://admin.socket.io/#/` and after successfully login it just shows following menu.

[image]

here is my connection snippet.

```
const app = express();

const http = require('http');
const { instrument } = require("@socket.io/admin-ui");

const server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["https://admin.socket.io"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

instrument(io, {
 auth: false
});
```

I want that all feature as shown in that menu.

- Sockets
- Rooms
- Clients
- Events

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Actually default mode is development but somehow it was not set when i set the mode to development it works fine for me.

```
const app = express();

const http = require('http');
const { instrument } = require("@socket.io/admin-ui");

const server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server, {
cors: {
    origin: ["https://admin.socket.io"],
    credentials: true,
},
 });

instrument(io, {
 auth: false,
 mode: "development"
});
```

reference : https://socket.io/docs/v4/admin-ui/#mode

[image]